# I want to reboot the system once a search had been done to see that no-one is logged in

Tags: reboot, wc, who

I'm working on a user menu so that when a user logs in all they get is this menu; on this menu is a selection of reboot option. I want one of the options to be reboot the system if no one is logged in.

I want a search to be carried out to see if anyone has logged in. I think this would be a good start:

```
# who | wc
```

if the answer were 0 users I'd want the system to reboot. **NOTE:** I know it won't be because the user is logged in using the menu.

How can I find out if there's no other user logged in besides the one accessing the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like what you're looking for. The issue as I see it is that there's always going to be at least 1 user that's logged in, i.e. the one accessing the menu, so you're looking for when the number of user's is 1.

```
$ who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l
1
```

This takes the output of `who` and cuts just the first column off, i.e. the usernames, and then sorts it uniquely, and then counts it.

But IMO, it's a bit more complicated than that. Looking at the situation in this manner is ignoring if this user has any logged in SSH sessions, for example. So you probably want to check to see if the above output from `who` specifies that it's only `:0` devices or if there are any `pts/#` types of lines.

#### Examples

```
# represents the login for the user's desktop on display :0
saml     :0           2014-12-01 01:56 (:0)

# represents user's terminals or SSH connections
saml     pts/0        2014-12-01 01:57 (:0)
```

**NOTE:** Notice how the `pts/0` line shows which display it's associated with, ":0".

So something like this seems more appropriate:

```
num_pts=$(who | grep 'pts/' | wc -l)
num_usr=$(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l)

if [ $num_pts -eq 0 ] && [ $num_usr -eq 1 ]; then echo "OK to logout";fi
```

#### Example

Here's a simulated run where I have 2 accounts logged in:

```
$ who
saml     :0           2014-12-01 01:56 (:0)
saml     pts/0        2014-12-01 01:57 (:0)
saml     pts/1        2014-12-01 02:13 (:0)
saml     pts/2        2014-12-03 04:22 (:0)
saml     pts/3        2014-12-05 08:14 (:0)
samtest  pts/4        2014-12-05 08:14 (localhost)
```

Running the commands manually produces this:

```
$ echo $num_usr
2
$ echo $num_pts
5
$ if [ $num_pts -eq 0 ] && [ $num_usr -eq 1 ]; then echo "OK to logout";fi
$
```

If I manually set the 2 variables, however, to simulate that I'm logged into ":0" and have no terminals open:

```
$ num_usr=1
$ num_pts=0
$ if [ $num_pts -eq 0 ] && [ $num_usr -eq 1 ]; then echo "OK to logout";fi
OK to logout
```

This can be condensed and is just to show you an approach.

Comment: thank you very much that does seem like a better solution XD

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
USERS=$(who | wc -l)
if [ $USERS = 0 ]
then
    reboot
fi
```

Using `wc -l` print the newline counts. Instead, if you don't use this option `wc` prints newline,  word, and byte counts.

Comment: I don't think this will work since it'll always display at least 1 user that's accessing the menu. So it would seem to me that you'd want to be checking if there was 1 use, no?

Comment: Sure. If you put it in a cron must work. If you will execute by hand you should replace 0 with 1, because you are logged in.

Comment: it doesnt have to work its for a university assignment i will not be submitting the working code just a document with the code on so  if i know it can work i should still get the marks i need. i am thinking of putting it into Cron but i'm not sure if it would look better

Comment: I would try and implement it as best you can. This example doesn't work. See my answer for why.